# Is the term 'Flaggen Kommunikation' correct?

Tags: translation

I'm looking for a translation of the term 'Flag Communication' meaning the communication for which some flags are used. How should this look in German? 'Flaggen Kommunikation' or maybe 'Flaggenkommunikation'?

Comment: You mean the communication with a [Flaggenalphabet](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flaggenalphabet)?

Comment: Yes, that's the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spelling of the proposed term *Flaggen Kommunikation* is not correct. The regular spelling of the compound is *Flaggenkommunikation.* If necessary, a hyphen may be used for emphasis by way of an exception *(Flaggen-Kommunikation)*.

However, in the United States Edition of the International Code of Signals, which includes detailed instructions for signaling by flags, this method of signaling is called “flag signaling”. A set of signal flags consists of twenty-six alphabetical flags, ten numeral pennants, three substitutes, and the answering pennant. This method of signaling is not to be confused with “Morse signaling by hand flags”.

The official German edition of the International Code of Signals is called *[Internationales Signalbuch](http://www.bsh.de/de/Produkte/Buecher/Sonstige_Publikationen/IntSignalbuch/index.jsp).* The term “flag signaling” is translated as *„Flaggensignalisieren“.* “Morse signaling by hand flags” is translated as *„Morsen mit Handflaggen“.* (Note that *Flaggensignalisieren* and *Morsen* are actually nominalized verbs.)